# Updating twitter status in an ajax call, using jmathai-twitter-async's library

Tags: php, jquery, twitter

I have a page with a textbox and a button, I want to post to twitter the contents of the textbox.

I have created an app on dev.twitter, I first check if the user is authenticated or not, then I add the following to the button's click event :

```
//sending message
$.post('postStatus.php',{
    status:message
    },function(response){
    $("#debug").html(response);
});
```

The file `postStatus.php` is (first draft) :

```
<?php
    require_once 'EpiCurl.php';
    require_once 'EpiOAuth.php';
    require_once 'EpiTwitter.php';
    require_once 'secret.php';

    //is connected ?
    /*
    $twitterObj = new EpiTwitter($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);
    $oauth_token = @$_GET['oauth_token'];
    if($oauth_token == '')
        die();
    */

    //validate message
    $message=@$_POST['status'];
    $message = trim($message);
    if ($message === '')
        die();

    //send
    $twitterObj->setToken($_COOKIE['oauth_token'],$_COOKIE['oauth_token_secret']);
    $status=$twitterObj->post_statusesUpdate(array('status' => $message));
    $status->response;
    echo 'Your status has been updated';
```

Am I missing something in the validation of `$message` ? What should I, if anything, enclose in try/catch blocks ? And finally, should I have `postStatus.php` return a 500 error, or is `die()` ok ?

Comment: $consumerKey and $consumerSecret are defined in the required secret.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PHP `$consumerKey` and `$consumerSecret` aren't defined + `$_GET['oauth_token']` will never be set because the url in your js is static.

Also you might want to escape the status before you attpemt to post it.

Comment: Oops, I copied the "is connected" part from another file ><. But consumerKey and Secret are defined in the required secret.php

Comment: Makes sense, then the only problem I see is that `$_GET['oauth_token']` is always empty because of static url in js.